# R Shiny: how to prevent duplicate plot update with nested selectors?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataset in which every row contains data about single person and every column contains different information about him/her. Let's say it looks like this (but more columns and rows in real data):

```
data <- data.frame(
  height=runif(1000, 150, 200),
  sex=sample(c("f","m"), 1000, replace=T),
  heir=sample(c("blond", "black", "red", "brown"), 1000, replace=T),
  eye=sample(c("blue", "green", "brown"to show histograms ), 1000, replace=T)
)
```

I want to make a Shiny app in which I could select a category (column) and a value and draw a histogram of `height` among people who share this value. For example for `category = 'sex'` and `value = 'f'` I would like to have a histogram of height among woman. Because each category have different set of values, after changing category I have to (automatically) update the value selector too. **The problem is that it means two updates and each of them generates new histogram, while only the second one makes any sense**. Here is my code:

## server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- data.frame(
    height=runif(1000, 150, 200),
    sex=sample(c("f","m"), 1000, replace=T),
    heir=sample(c("blond", "black", "red", "brown"), 1000, replace=T),
    eye=sample(c("blue", "green", "brown"), 1000, replace=T)
    )
  
  # update value after category change
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "value", "Value",
                      choices=as.list(levels(data[,input$category])))
    cat(paste("category update:",input$category, "\n"), file = stderr())
  })
  
  output$histogram <- renderPlot({
    cat(paste("hist:", "category =", input$category,
              "value =",input$value, "\n"), file = stderr())
    hist(data[data[, input$category] == input$value, "height"])
  })
})
```

## ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(    
    selectInput("category", "Category", choices=c("sex", "heir", "eye"), selected="sex"),
    selectInput("value", "Value", c("f", "m"), selected="f")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("histogram")
  )
))
```

The `cat` expressions makes it easier to see what is going on. When I run the app the default category ('sex') and value ('f') is selected, so the console output is:

```
category update: sex 
hist: category = sex value = f
```

Then, when I choose the different category using the selector, for example heir, I got an information:

```
category update: heir 
hist: category = heir value = f 
Error in hist.default(data[data[, input$category] == input$value, "height"]): 
  invalid number of 'breaks'
hist: category = heir value = black
```

So at first, the app changes the category and tries to plot a histogram for the new `category = heir` and old `value = f`, which of course have to fail. Only then it changes the `value` and then draws correct histogram. **Is there any way to automatically update the `value` selector before any plot is drawn?**

Comment: You can maybe try wrapping all the `input$category` in your `output$histogram` in `isolate`. This will make the histogram not reactive to `input$category`. It will still be reactive to `input$value` so it will still update when you change category as that changes the value as well.

Comment: @NicE that's what I'm looking for! Could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isolate`to avoid dependency of your histogram on `input$category`:

```
  output$histogram <- renderPlot({
    cat(paste("hist:", "category =", isolate(input$category),
              "value =",input$value, "\n"), file = stderr())
    hist(data[data[, isolate(input$category)] == input$value, "height"])
  })
```

Your histogram will no longer be updated when the category changes. Changing the category also changes the value in your app, and the histogram will update when that value is changed.

More info on `isolate` [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html).